# Pivot Table with vba

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a Pivot table using vba. I need the code to take a sheet and create a pivot using all the data in it. 
For columns in the pivot i need: "Years" first and then "Document Date"
For Row "Arrears after net due date"
For values I need the sum of "Amount"

I tried this code below but it gives me an "Object required error" 
I've never make pivots before so I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track.

```
Sub newPVT()

Set Rng = wsA.Range("A1:AA100000")
Set rngData = Range(Rng, Rng.End(xlToRight))
Set rngData = Range(Rng, Rng.End(xlDown))
Set rngB = wsB.Range("C8")

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, 
    SourceData:=rngData, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable 
    TableDestination:=rngB, TableName:="pvtReportA_B", 
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

End Sub
```

Comment: You have plenty of undefined variables, or probably defined elsewhere but not visible in this scope. In either case it's too hard to debug, I urge you to use `Option Explicit` and start from there. The error message seems to say that `wsA` and/or `wsB` are not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the pivot table to an object:

```
Sub newPVT()

Dim Rng As Range, rngData As Range, rngB As Range
Dim pvt As PivotTable 


Set wsA = Worksheets("Name of your sheet")
Set Rng = wsA.Range("A1:AA100000")
Set rngData = Range(Rng, Rng.End(xlToRight))
Set rngData = Range(Rng, Rng.End(xlDown))
Set rngB = wsB.Range("C8")

Set pvt = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, 
    SourceData:=rngData, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable 
    TableDestination:=rngB, TableName:="pvtReportA_B", 
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

End Sub
```